# replies to thread box very restricted

Tags: discussion, editing

one can write a question and have paragraphs etc, add images.
reply to a reply and hit enter for a paragraph and the typing gets posted !
small little box to type in.

also I have to wait 40 mins it says before posting another question !

also I cant post unless I choose a tag but the tags available dont cover my subject at all.

could blender get a better forum interface as others have ?

Steve

Comment: You have [already asked this before](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2619/reply-box-has-character-count-and-also-time-limits) Comments are not for extended discussions, hence the intentional limitations. This is not a traditional forum for regular conversations, tags help guarantee your questions are on topic. If existing tags seem unhelpful your question is very likely off topic anyway

Comment: We're a little bit different from other sites. This site is not a forum at all. There are no threads but a single question and multiple answers. Comments are meant to help users guide the question toward answers, they are not meant to have conversations or discussions or to have personalized support for a single project. **This site is all about getting answers. It's not a discussion forum. There's no chit-chat**.  This is not tweeter or social media. Please take the [tour] to understand how the site works.

Comment: Comments are not answers. Use comments to ask for more information or clarify a question or answer. They are not editable after 5 minutes. That is how the site works. Questions and answers can be edited, there is no time limit and they can be formated with paragraphs and images

Answer (score 3):

The time limits are because you are new (basically spam prevention).

#### Comments

What you are experiencing is the difference between posts (questions and answers) and comments **not** some kind of "replies to a thread."

Comments are meant to be short and simple (not an answer). There are no need for paragraphs, nor a full blown editor in the input box. You rarely need a larger input box for a comment (comments are limited to 600 characters anyway), but it *can* be resized. Just drag the bottom right corner.

Questions and answers (the real content of the site) is where everything happens. It is here you get [full formatting](https://blender.stackexchange.com/editing-help), images, pretty code, etc. Because SE is a Q&A site, not a forum, the comments are treated much differently then questions or answers.

Nope SE will never change this core model to incorporate more "forum like" responses or features. Why? [SE is not a forum](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/92107/278094). The [site tour](https://blender.stackexchange.com/tour) does a pretty good job of showing what SE *is* and how it works.

As an example: with an ideal question, there is no "discussion" there are no replies, or digging through pages of threads to find the answer. Simply a question, and answer(s) to that question. PS Anything posted in the answer section that does not attempt to answer the question will be deleted.

[blenderartists](http://blenderartists.org/) (a forum) is great for art feedback and discussion. BSE is not for any kind of discussion. (If you want to discuss take it to [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8888/the-renderfarm) or off site.)

Forum = message board for open discussion
BSE = Q&A site for blender

#### Tags

I'd be *very* surprised if we have no tags that cover your blender questions. Yet if there really are none then maybe that is telling you that your question is off topic. You might want to double check that if you find no suitable tags.